Use dexie-cloud with vanilla js
I'm evaluating the use of dexie incl dexie-cloud in a vanilla js project. It's actually just a "Custom Code" section of a low-code tool.
As I would like to keep things simple here, I'm looking for a vanilla js solution.
Using dexie itself works without issues, it is even documented here: https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Hello-World
But there is no sample including the dexie-cloud addin https://dexie.org/cloud/#getting-started. I tried different approches like:

Using normal <script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie-cloud-addon@4.0.8/dist/umd/dexie-cloud-addon.js">
Realising that this is an AMD Module, I used a <script type="module">import Dexie from "https://unpkg.com/dexie@4.0.8/dist/dexie.js"...

But I can't get it to work. Has anyone used dexie-cloud within a vanilla js page?

There was a similar question on github discussion: https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/discussions/1826
Use script includes to include the UMD version of:

dexie
rxjs
dexie-cloud-addon


Hi! Thank you very much for your fast response. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work here. I used the html snippet exactly like posted, and then rearranged it so that rxjs included first:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at dexie-cloud-addon.js:19:1)

I used a different platform now, which offers it's own solution to custom profile data, so I can move forward now.

https://codepen.io/gprossliner-the-styleful/pen/BaXorpP?editors=1111

I'm sorry you didn't get it to work. If scrolling down the thread I referred to, you could see the solution that worked for the user having the same request as you had. I think you copied his original failing code instead of the final solution. https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/discussions/1826#discussioncomment-7617498

I have seen that it has been marked as an answer on the post. I tried the code from the answer (and I'm still unable to figure out why it worked, because every script is pined to a specific version). If you checkout the codepen snippet, you should be able to confirm that.
Just for information: The reasoning behind switching to a different platform was not driven by this problem, but for business requirements.
